# htaccess rules ignore some strings on url

Tags: .htaccess

need help

i have a link like this

```
http://www.mysite.com/obj/task/land/city/41277/landId/19/Best+Restaurant//Sville%20city
```

using htaccess

```
RewriteRule ^l/([0-9]+)/([0-9]+)/?$ index.php?obj=obj&task=land&city=$1&landId=$2
RewriteRule ^l/([0-9]+)/([0-9]+)$ index.php?obj=obj&task=land&city=$1&landId=$2
```

now my link looks like this

```
 http://www.mysite.com/l/41277/19
```

what should i add on my htaccess so that my link like this will be accepted

```
http://www.mysite.com/l/41277/19/Best+Restaurant//Sville%20city
http://www.mysite.com/l/41247/17/Best+parks/Cold%20Province/Platinum%20city
```

Comment: I will accept billions of down vote but please leave a comment.

Comment: what the last links should be rewritten to ?

Comment: i want htaccess to ignore it. on the long url when i remove it like the '/Best+Restaurant//Sville%20city' the site stills load. but in the new url when i add it the site has no output.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Enable mod_rewrite and .htaccess through `httpd.conf` and then put this code in your `.htaccess` under `DOCUMENT_ROOT` directory:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks -MultiViews
# Turn mod_rewrite on
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^l/([0-9]+)/([0-9]+)/? /index.php?obj=obj&task=land&city=$1&landId=$2 [L,QSA,NC]
```

Comment: Thank you very much for the help Mr.anubhava

Comment: You're most welcome. I share your pain that some folks here down vote without leaving any comment. IMO SO shouldn't allow that.

Comment: Thank you. i agree that IMO SO shouldn't allow down voting a question without a comment. users who ask question get a down vote,vote to close and no one explains why, would have to think why their question was down voted.Thank you again.